# How check two DOM equal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom

I have custom form for make perfect UX, have one field with button plus to add some details information, this field has validation (avoid the same value of the field) that i need to check DOM if is equal or not. Equality I need is the same DOM, not like code.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
    <select> ... </select><span class="btn"> + </span>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#form select").on('change', changeForm );

function changeForm() {
    var check = $(this);
    $("#form select").each(function(){ // In first index is exactly equal of variable check
        if (check == $(this)) { ... } // false
        if (check === $(this)) { ... } // false
        if (check.isEqualNode($(this)) { ... } // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
        if (check.isSameNode($(this)) { ... } // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    }
}
```

Has code to return true? Or my code doesn't is good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if (check.is(this)) { ... }
```

Comment: obs: lacked a parenthesis in IF

Answer (score 0):

jQuery constructor returns a new jQuery object and 2 different objects are not considered equal.

You could get the wrapped DOM element and compare it:

```
if ( check.get(0) === this )
```